# Font Awesome em select box

Tags: html5, css3

Estou com problemas em exibir alguns 'icones' da FontAwesome como no exemplo, note que um icone é exibido entretanto o segundo não, além disso quando clico no select box a primeira opção também não exibe o icone corretamente. Como posso corrigir tais erros?

```css
select {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      -o-appearance: none;
      -ms-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "Roboto";
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #727272;
      border: none;
      margin-right: 10px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="lang">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Português &#xf078;</option>
    <option value="2">English</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option value="1">BRL &#xf17b;</option>
    <option value="2">USD</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Deve colocar o icon numa tag propria de forma a ser exibido correctamente.

```
<select>
    <option value="1">BRL <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></option>
    <option value="2">USD</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Vc poderia explicar como fez para a tag `<i>` funcionar dentro de um select?

Comment: Basta adiciona-lo dentro de qualquer <option>. O tag <i> serve identificar um icon.

Comment: Desculpe, acho que não fui claro. A questão é porque um ícone funciona o outro não usando unicode diretamente.

Comment: Porque o metodo correcto de utilização é através do tag <i>, sendo que, por unicode, o html não vai reconhecer directamente o unicode do font awesome, pois o mesmo é próprio.